# What happens if you remove a game app on Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-games

If you remove a game app in Google Plus, does your game account and game data get removed from the game's database? Or does it depend on the game's publisher?

I wonder what's Google Plus's policy about my inquiry.

Comment: It would be easy enough to test this. Start using a game on G+. Play for a few days (enough to make some progress). Revoke permissions on the game. Wait a few days. Sign up for the game again and see if you're still as far along as you were.

Comment: looking into policy would be necessary as , although your game progress is deleted , the app publishers might still retain your data , it has happened to me with zynga

Comment: Google+ games were removed years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the creator of the game.

> If the game developer has created an account for you on their own systems, removing permissions for a game doesn't necessarily delete your account with them. You'll need to contact the developer if you want them to remove your account or delete information they have stored about you. To find developer contact information, we suggest visiting the game developer’s website.

Source: [Removing permissions for a game](http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1334234)